three-way nested ANOVA
I spent a while trying to solve this problem about analyzing a three-way nested ANOVA. Here is a fake dataset and example with R:
set.seed(100)
ps=factor(paste("countries_",rep(letters[1:3],each=200),sep=""))
vs=factor(paste("cities_",rep(rep(letters[1:4],each=50),3),sep=""))
qs=factor(paste("neighborhoods_",rep(rep(rep(letters[1:5],each=10),4),3),sep=""))
x=vector(mode="numeric",length=600)
for (i in 1:600) x[i]=rnorm(1)*2+as.integer((i-1)/10)
dataset=data.frame(countries=ps,cities=vs,neighborhoods=qs,values=x)
attach(dataset)

All three factors are random, the second one is nested within the first one, and the third one is nested within the second one. I thus adjust the following model (with lme4):
library(lme4)
mod=lmer(x~(1| countries)+(1| countries: cities)+(1| countries: cities: neighborhoods))

And I decided to test the (three) random effects with the package lmerTest (but performing standard LRT gives obviously the same results):
library(lmerTest)
rand(mod)

That leads to the following results:
ANOVA-like table for random-effects: Single term deletions

Model:
1 | countries) + (1 | countries:cities) + (1 | countries:cities:neighborhoods)
                                     npar  logLik    AIC     LRT Df Pr(>Chisq)    
<none>                                  5 -1370.4 2750.8  
(1 | countries)                         4 -1378.0 2764.0  15.151  1  9.924e-05 ***
(1 | countries:cities)                  4 -1422.4 2852.8 103.999  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
(1 | countries:cities:neighborhoods)    4 -1440.5 2888.9 140.085  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

I do not understand these results, and I thus suspect there is a mistake somewhere. Indeed, the "countries" effect should be the stronger, then the "cities" effect, and then the "neighborhoods" effect, while the LRT are showing the opposite trend (i.e., the "countries" effect looks to be the weaker one, etc.). Also, I remained unable to understand why all Chi2 have 1 df only. This does not make any sense to me.
Any help on that would be (more than) welcomed.
Best, Eric.

After thinking about this quite a while, I guess I'm starting to understand.
The LRT are not proportional to the effect sizes, but these are the variance components that are related to the importance of the effects, as this can be seen in the summary of the fitted model.
Also, for each random factor, the model fitting procedure estimates the variance for this factor, i.e., one parameter only. This explains why 1 df in each case.
HTH, Eric.
